# How to create a matrix with sum products for each element

Tags: python, numpy

I'm pretty new in python and I want to create matrix A for the following function, where every element is a sum in regards to i, including the given fi functions.

[image: Function]

[image: Functions2]

So far I have tried different methods, but am struggling to use the index sum in each element.

```
f1 = np.sin(pi*x)
f2 = np.sin((2/3)*pi*x)

vector_b = np.array([f0 * y, f1 * y, f2 * y])

x_datapoints = len(x)
y_datapoints = len(y)

matrix_A = np.empty((x_datapoints, y_datapoints))
for i in range(x_datapoints):
    for j in range(y_datapoints):
        matrix_A[i][j] = x[i]**j
```

Also tried something like this but it got me no where as well:

```
first = [f0 *f0], [f0 * f1], [f0 * f2]
second = [f1 * f0], [f1 * f1], [f1 * f2]
third = [f2 * f0], [f2 * f1], [f2 * f2]

matrix_A = [first, second, third]
```

Appreciate your answers :)

Comment: This looks like a college exam question. I'll wait 00:00 to help :v

Comment: It's a part of an assignment :)

Answer (score 2):

your matrix is sum of all outer products of [f_0(x_i), f_1(x_i), f_2(x_i)]

**Using Matrix multiplication**

```
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi

x = np.random.rand(1000)

f0 = np.sin((2)*pi*x)
f1 = np.sin(np.pi*x)
f2 = np.sin((2/3)*pi*x)

f = np.array([f0 , f1 , f2 ]).T

A = f[:,:,np.newaxis]@f[:,np.newaxis,:]  ## performing outer product i.e f*f^T
A = np.sum(A,axis =0) ## suming over all xi's
```

**Using einsum**

```
import numpy as np
pi = np.pi

x = np.random.rand(1000)

f0 = np.sin((2)*pi*x)
f1 = np.sin(np.pi*x)
f2 = np.sin((2/3)*pi*x)

f = np.array([f0 , f1 , f2 ])

A = np.einsum('ji,ki->jk',f,f)  ##This is using einsum
```